# maven can't make compile phase in netbeans 7.4 for j2ee ejb proj

Tags: maven, jpa, netbeans, ejb

I'm using web application type of the Project for ejb, jpa, jsf project.  When I coded test operations on connect to and row creation in db, the following error is drop out:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project DE: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence}persistence was not found in the project
-> [Help 1]
```

When I've tried to mannually to reach to C:\User{Name}.m2 dir in the terminal, I got the message: that "No such file or directory"

Please, I ask for the solution for this error.

Maybe the reason is that the project isn't correctly configured?

Comment: I'm accomplishing the operations on connect and insert operation in main method (for only tets reasons). And when I'd tried to mannually set up the maven configuration.xml file, I got the abovementioned error on @existance )

Comment: So the question is revealed how to correctly configure jee7 jpa, ejb, jsf (richFaces) web application Project in NB 7.4